# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Braintree dropin UI

Tags: javascript, braintree

I use braintree.dropin , to create front-end for credit card form.

### payment_method.html (I masked out authorization value with ???)

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.12.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
  <button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
  <script>

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/72437
    function post(path, params, method) {
      method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

      // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
      // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
      var form = document.createElement("form");
      form.setAttribute("method", method);
      form.setAttribute("action", path);

      for (var key in params) {
          if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
              hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
              hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
              hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

              form.appendChild(hiddenField);
          }
      }

      document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
    }

    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

    braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: '???',
      container: '#dropin-container'
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
          post('/billing/subscribe/', 
            {
              'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'lDqtKKosE9yBGtKmFv4BSBvDCGEX1WPsY0JOy0XlZC5Vnc6zR5BQmuCzkhzeS1PJ',
              'subscription_plan': 2,
              'payload_nonce': payload.nonce
            }
          );
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

However, I'm getting this warning message, after submitting credit card information.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://origin-analytics-sand.sandbox.braintree-api.com/cn2rcqfn435vtj63.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

[image]

Although the whole process works fine (I manage to make payment without problem), I afraid perhaps I should fix warning, to avoid any security loop hole. It is caused by `post` function called.

However, I have no idea what is the reason for such warning, and how I should fix it.

As, my page's domain is `localhost`, and I'm performing POST back to `localhost` domain. I thought this is not cross domain issue? Where does the `https://origin-analytics-sand.sandbox.braintree-api.com/cn2rcqfn435vtj63` warning comes from then?

Any idea?

### What I had tested

If I perform `post` function called, outside `instance.requestPaymentMethod`'s callback function scope, cross-origin warning will not occur. Of course, I can't do that because I need `payload.nonce` from `instance.requestPaymentMethod`'s callback function.